# Detect entry to parent component from child component Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

I'm trying to find a way to detect when I have entered the parent component from child component. Since the parent component is already loaded when accessing the child, I cannot use the mounted() nor the created() life-cycle hook when entering back into the parent component.

Below code is an example of how my routes are layed out. When I navigate back to '/foo' from '/foo/bar', how can I detect that in the Foo component?

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/foo', component: Foo, 
  children: [
    { path: 'bar', component: Bar }
  ]}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [navigation guard](https://meet.google.com/osu-vpvf-kez) to get the previous route and do your check.

In your parent component you can add this:

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
 // here you can save to and check it in mounted for instance
 // call next and pass a callback to access the component when it is ready
 next(parentComp => {
   parentComp.navigatedFrom = from
 })
},
```

And then you can access `navigatedFrom` from inside your parent component.

Comment: This only works when going from ex: /link1 to /link2 but not when going from child: /link1/child to /link1

Comment: You could also try beforeRouteUpdate. This should work

Comment: Awesome. Now it updates when I go to parent, but why does it also run when I navigate between every child component. it runs when I go from /foo/child1 to /foo/child2. I only need it when it goes from /foo/child1 back to /foo.